# Process XHTML (well-formatted XML) unordered list data to grouped and sorted XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to transform an an XHTML document (well-formatted XML) to a standard XML document.

**Input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>HTML Document Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="a.html" title="abcdef AAA">New York</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="b.html" title="abcdef AAA">Los Angles</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="c.html" title="abcdef AAA">Alaska</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="d.html" title="abcdef BBB">Florida</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="e.html" title="zyxwvu AAA"><em>California</em></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Note:** I noticeed that having the DOCTYPE declaration and simple comments cause failure during XSLT parsing. So, I manually remove them before XSL parse. To parse the output properly, currently using 'xhtml:' prefix as provided at the post: [Can I parse an HTML using XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639625/can-i-parse-an-html-using-xslt).

Group the elements based on the  tags title value (sub-string 2nd part), e.g. AAA, BBB, etc. Further grouping on the 1st part of the title attribute value (e.g. abcdef / zyxwvu) or the presence of <em> tag.
There would be totally four elements, such as <root>, <element>, <abcdef> and <zyxwvu> in the output. This is desired.

**Expected Output:**

```
<root>
    <element title="hard-coded title" href="hard-coded url">
        <element title="AAA" href="AAA.html">
            <abcdef>
                <element title="Alaska" href="c.html">
                <element title="Los Angles" href="b.html">
                <element title="New York" href="a.html">
            </abcdef>
            <zyxwvu>
                <element title="California" href="e.html">
            </zyxwvu>
        </element>
        <element title="BBB" href="BBB.html">
            <abcdef>
                <element title="Florida" href="d.html">
            </abcdef>
        </element>
    </element>
</root>
```

Would appreciate if the solution is provided in both XSLT v1.0 & v2.0.

Comment: People will be more inclined to help you if you make an effort. What have you tried, and what isn't working? The way you've asked the question, it's as if you want the responder to produce the entire solution.

Comment: Yes, I need somebody's assistance for the entire solution for this. I tried the key as `<xsl:key name="keyId" match="xhtml:a" use="substring-after(xhtml:li/xhtml:a/@title, ' ')" />`, but unable to define the generate-id() function for grouping purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 exclude-result-prefixes="x">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kaByTail" match="x:a"
  use="substring-after(@title, ' ')"/>

 <xsl:key name="kaByHeadAndTail" match="x:a"
  use="concat(substring-before(@title, ' '),
              '+',
              substring-after(@title, ' ')
              )"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vAncors" select="//x:a"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
    <element title="hard-coded title" href="hard-coded url">
     <xsl:for-each select=
      "$vAncors
         [generate-id()
         =
          generate-id(key('kaByTail',
                           substring-after(@title, ' ')
                          )
                           [1]
                      )
         ]">
         <xsl:variable name="vKey"
              select="substring-after(@title, ' ')"/>

         <xsl:variable name="vGroup" select=
         "key('kaByTail', $vKey)"/>

        <element title="{$vKey}" href="{$vKey}.html">

         <xsl:for-each select=
         "$vGroup
            [generate-id()
            =
             generate-id(key('kaByHeadAndTail',
                             concat(substring-before(@title, ' '),
                                   '+',
                                    $vKey
                                    )
                            )
                             [1]
                         )
             ]

         ">
          <xsl:variable name="vKey2"
               select="substring-before(@title, ' ')"/>

          <xsl:element name="{$vKey2}">
           <xsl:for-each select=
            "key('kaByHeadAndTail',
                 concat($vKey2,'+',$vKey)
                 )">
            <xsl:sort/>
            <element title="{.}" href="{@href}"/>
           </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:element>
         </xsl:for-each>
        </element>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </element>
  </root>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>HTML Document Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="a.html" title="abcdef AAA">New York</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="b.html" title="abcdef AAA">Los Angles</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="c.html" title="abcdef AAA">Alaska</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="d.html" title="abcdef BBB">Florida</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="e.html" title="zyxwvu AAA"><em>California</em></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<root>
   <element title="hard-coded title" href="hard-coded url">
      <element title="AAA" href="AAA.html">
         <abcdef>
            <element title="Alaska" href="c.html"/>
            <element title="Los Angles" href="b.html"/>
            <element title="New York" href="a.html"/>
         </abcdef>
         <zyxwvu>
            <element title="California" href="e.html"/>
         </zyxwvu>
      </element>
      <element title="BBB" href="BBB.html">
         <abcdef>
            <element title="Florida" href="d.html"/>
         </abcdef>
      </element>
   </element>
</root>
```

**Explanation**: Nested Muenchian grouping using first a single, then a composite grouping key.key

Comment: Amazing reply Dimitre Novatchev !!