# What is the fastest way to remove html tags from a document in java?

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup, html, htmlcleaner

I have bunch of web document and want to remove the html tags from it. I saw some posts on StackOverflow on how to do in java, all from regex to HtmlCleaner and Jsoup.

I am interested in finding the fastest way to do it. I have millions of documents, so performance is crucial in my case. I can even trade a bit of quality for the performance.

Thanks for any answers in advance.

Comment: you'd have to measure it

Comment: thanks, i know that. i wonder if somebody has done that before and can share the results.

Comment: What exactly do you need as a result.  Is this just screen scraping?

Comment: @frankmoss: *"I saw some posts on StackOverflow on how to do it in Java, all from regex to..."*  I take it it wasn't this answer with 4435 upvotes (as I type this): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags   : )

Comment: If your Html is strict or XHTML. Use XSLT, here is a kind-[xhtml and XSLT][1]related


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639625/can-i-parse-an-html-using-xslt

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen thats exactly what i want, scraping and as fast as possible! I only need the plain text.

Comment: Install "links" or "lynx" in your operating system and call that with the option to dump what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the java regexp is the fastest solution. However, it degrades the quality of the text obtained after.

Comment: It is *not* possible to parse HTML with regexps: See first answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is to use as much as possible stream/SAX processing:
1) because it uses less memory
2) it is fast
3) can be more easier parallelized (consequence of low memory consumption)

Those factors are needed (from my pov) by your use cases where you have million of documents.
please see there [Wikipedia SAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML)

So if your Html is strict or XHTML. Use XSLT, and here is a tuto on how to transform XML (XHTML) using SAX [XSLT+SAX+Java](http://oreilly.com/catalog/javaxslt/chapter/ch05.html).

And finally, if you DON'T have an XML valid HTML please, look at this [Java: Replace Strings in Streams, Arrays, Files etc.](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-howto/replace-strings-in-streams-arrays-files.html) which make use of stream (and PushBackReader).

HTH

Comment: I am working with web documents, i.e., it is not a well-formed XML. Using Tidy or something similar would introduce an overhead. Thanks for the link (PushBackReader), will check it out.

Comment: Let me know if it has helped... or even if you need further help this way

Answer (score 0):

1) if html is proper xml then you can create its document object and remove the node.

2) if it is not proper xml then read entire html as string & and use replace function to remove "html" sunbstring.

If HTMl is not proper xml then regex  is fastest way to replace in a string.

Comment: 1) The problem with document is that they all have to be loaded and parsed in memory, so that it will have a big footprint, moreover the fact that if the html is huge, you can reach heap problems.
2) Regex has been advertised by @user988052 to be unrelevant, please to follow the question link

Comment: @andy petrella:- that's what I conveyed. If html is proper xml one can use sax/dom parsing to remove the node.

one can use replace function of string and in that replace string can be specified as regex

Comment: @DS28 I am working with  Web documents. So forget about proper xml. I was fearing that the best shot would be the regex but it seems I will have to either go with it or use jsoup.

Comment: @frankmoss:- If html is not proper then you can directly use Java String class. HTML opening tag will always be present at starting & HTML closing tag will be at the end of document. So you don't need to search entire document just search first occurrence from top and first occurrence from bottom & replace it. This would avoid searching entire document for html tags.

Comment: @frankmoss:- If by html tags you meant standard html tags then also you can use replace function,that can take regex as input & will remove all the strings according to regex. Many api use this function in turn. But what makes search faster is that proper xml is a form Tree structure. So its obvious that search & replace would be faster with Tree structure rather then linear search. Hope you got my point.