# Referencing an image placed with the rich text editor in Umbraco

Tags: xml, image, xslt, xpath, umbraco

Is there a way to reference images (with xslt) that have been placed into the rich text editor of an Umbraco page. I would like to pull these images from existing news story pages and load them into a macro for a slide show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if this post if of any help to you?

[Can I parse an HTML using XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639625/can-i-parse-an-html-using-xslt)

Personally I would user a razor script and Html Agility Pack, which will allow you to parse the html like xml.

If you would like an example, look here: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples

Comment: Used a razor script without the Agility Pack

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can do something like this against whichever content you're reading:

```
<xsl:template match="img">
  <img alt="{@alt}" src="{@src}" />
</xsl:template>
```

But I'm not sure if the content you'll be querying will be parseable xml or not.

You could also try doing it with razor and bring in the html agility pack: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ This would probably be a bit more fault-tolerant.